# biologically related people more susceptible to epidemics?

Tags: epidemiology

Are biologically related people more susceptible to epidemics? Say, one of the parents got a cold, is it easier for the child to be infected than is the other parent?

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in the [help] and the reasons mentioned in [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for the comments but what's unclear to you? Please raise then I'll edit